# Trello API since lastView

Tags: api, trello

I don't know if this is the right place for this question but I hope anyone knows the answer!
I want to use the `since=lastView` option in https://trello.com/docs/api/board/.
Does anyone knows what this means exactly? The lastView for this special board via API or for this special board but for the user including the API or maybe the last view of the user at all and not on this special board.

Thanks, I couldn't find any information inside the trello documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`since=lastView` is how the unread activity indicator is rendered in the Trello apps.  The view is thus per board, but the routes that can update that record "views" are private.  I would suggest using `since` with a date for most uses.